# setTimeout on a high volume data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have tried googling and searching entirety of stack overflow for this question but I think it boils down to the keywords I'm using to search.

Basically my problem boils down to the following: `when the cursor leaves an element, wait 500 milliseconds before closing the element. Before close the element, check if the cursor is back in the element, and if its not, do not hide it`.

I'm using `vuejs` to do this but I boiled down the problem to being in `setTimeout` function. The part where I have the code is fairly complex to post it here, therefore I created a simple `POC` to demonstrate the problem:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ul v-for="x in 2000" :key="x">
      <li @mouseenter="handleMouseEnter(x)" @mouseleave="handleMouseLeave(x)" style="height: 50px;">
        Hello
        <span style="background-color: red" v-show="showBox[x]">BOX</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {},
  methods: {
    handleMouseEnter(index) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        let showBox = [...this.showBox];
        showBox[index] = true;
        this.showBox = showBox;
      }, 500);
    },
    handleMouseLeave(index) {
      let showBox = [...this.showBox];
      showBox[index] = false;
      this.showBox = showBox;
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showBox: []
    };
  },
  created() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 2000; i++) {
      this.showBox[i] = false;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

You can checkout the sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-river-ruz7b

If you hover over from top to bottom in a moderate speed you will realize that even after leaving the `li` element the red box stays.

I guess the problem lays in the fact that `handleMouseEnter` is being called with a `setTimeout` and the `handleMouseLeave` is not. Therefore, making `handleMouseEnter` be executed after `handleMouseLeave` therefore showing the box.

Any light would be highly appreciated here and if a short explanation could be given on why the problem is happening it would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example seems to operate the opposite way round to the original problem description (the timer is on showing not hiding) but I think I get what you mean.

As you suggest, the problem is that the timer callback is being called after the `mouseleave` event fires. So the red box does get hidden but shortly thereafter the timer fires and brings it back.

In the example below I have simply cancelled the timer using `clearTimeout`. In general it might be necessary to store an array of such timers, one for each element, but in this specific example I believe it only makes sense to have one timer active at once so I can get away without an array.

I also moved the initial population of `showBox` into `data`. There seemed no reason to use a `created` hook here.

There's no need to copy the whole array each time, you can just use `$set` to set the value in the existing array. I haven't changed that in my example.

I would also note that for this particular example you don't need an array to hold all the `showBox` values. Only one red box can be visible at once so you only need a single property to hold the index of the currently visible box. I haven't changed this in my example as I suspect your real use case is not as straight forward as this.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  methods: {
    handleMouseEnter(index) {
      this.currentTimer = setTimeout(() => {
        let showBox = [...this.showBox];
        showBox[index] = true;
        this.showBox = showBox;
      }, 500);
    },
    handleMouseLeave(index) {
      clearTimeout(this.currentTimer)
      let showBox = [...this.showBox];
      showBox[index] = false;
      this.showBox = showBox;
    }
  },
  data() {
    const showBox = [];

    for (let i = 0; i <= 2000; i++) {
      showBox[i] = false;
    }

    return {
      showBox
    };
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul v-for="x in 2000" :key="x">
    <li @mouseenter="handleMouseEnter(x)" @mouseleave="handleMouseLeave(x)" style="height: 50px;">
      Hello
      <span style="background-color: red" v-show="showBox[x]">BOX</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```